# Checking camera calibration

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have calibrated a camera and want to check how good the calibration is. I have used the camera_calibration package to calibrate the camera, and the camera_info now looks like this:

```
  seq: 107890
  stamp: 
    secs: 1644410751
    nsecs: 887102635
  frame_id: "tb3_1/camera"
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: "plumb_bob"
D: [0.02671649678130836, -0.06818375047433628, 0.001356081223209799, -2.099463419728962e-05, 0.0]
K: [649.0186923124629, 0.0, 315.2563179012676, 0.0, 651.6174092664056, 235.6077408121116, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [649.7420654296875, 0.0, 314.7318835226943, 0.0, 0.0, 651.9991455078125, 235.5246928536799, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
```

In the package there is a cameracheck.py that should let you check how good the calibration is, but this does not run. I've made sure I'm using the rectified image by using the image_proc package.

Running it like this does not work:

```
python3 cameracheck.py --size 8x6 --square 0.25 image:=/cv_camera/image_rect_color camera:=/cv_camera
```

And running it like this does not work either:

```
python3 cameracheck.py --size 8x6 --square 0.25 image:=/cv_camera/image_rect_color monocular:=/forearm
```

The node just does nothing, running it results in no response.

As an alternative I tried following https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html to check how good the calibration is, but I don't fully understand what the values mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs are supposed to be. The mtx should be K, dist is D, but how do I get tvecs and rvecs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395839/checking-camera-calibration/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2022-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both `cameracalibrator.py` and `cameracheck.py` are ROS Nodes, shouldn't you use rather `rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py ...` / `rosrun camera_calibration cameracheck.py ...`?

From [the documentation there](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration):

> **4. NODES**
>
> 4.1 **cameracalibrator.py**
>
> cameracalibrator.py subscribes to ROS
> raw image topics, and presents a
> calibration window. It can run in both
> monocular and stereo modes. The
> calibration window shows the current
> images from the cameras, highlighting
> the checkerboard. When the user
> presses the CALIBRATE button, the node
> computes the camera calibration
> parameters. When the user clicks
> COMMIT, the node uploads these new
> calibration parameters to the camera
> driver using a service call.

...

> 4.2 **cameracheck.py**
>
> cameracheck.py subscribes to ROS
> rectified image topics and their
> associated camera_info, and prints out
> an error estimate. It can run in both
> monocular and stereo modes. The
> program expects to see a standard
> checkerboard target.

You should publish your ROS rectified images to the correct topics, then `cameracheck.py` will prints out error estimates.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2022-02-08**:
I did try rosrun for the nodes but an eariler error made it so I had to use python3 to run instead, it should still run the nodes as usual though. I have followed the cameracalibrator documentation, have calibrated using a checkerboard, commited and then the calibration parameters were uploaded. Then using image_proc the rectified images are published to /cv_camera/image_rect_color or /cv_camera/image_rect depending on if you want colors or not.

So now that the rectified image is being published you can use it in the cameracheck.py like this: `python3 cameracheck.py --size 8x6 --square 0.25 image:=/cv_camera/image_rect_color monocular:=/forearm`, but the node does not respond and does nothing

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-02-09**:
What was this error with the nodes at the start? Maybe it is something to fix. Did you check images being published? You can try to compile [the package from source](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/tree/noetic/camera_calibration) after adding there some printed logs (just to see the responsiveness of the node) and use it to test it

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2022-02-09**:
The error was because of the node using python2, same issue as described here; https://answers.ros.org/question/385702/ros-noetic-runninh-camera_checker-shows-no-module-named-rospkg/. Images are being published, confirmed through image_view. Will try to compile from source and add the print though

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-02-09**:
It is possible that the package has some bugs there - and maybe you can add your fix there/on your fork later! :)

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2022-02-09**:
Does the cameracheck.py work for you? I've seen several people not managing to get it work but noone says if they got it working eventually or not

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-02-09**:
Right now I don't use ROS1 but ROS2 + I am working remotely, so I don't have direct access to laboratory right now :( I will try to check it in my free time but don't expect it soon

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-11**:
Sorry for long time without response. Can you try these steps from [this blog post](https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-perform-pose-estimation-using-an-aruco-marker/) to check your camera and it's calibration? I didn't get this package to work either but [OpenCV has an instruction](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) to calculate Re-projection Error (bottom of the page) which gives a good estimation of just how exact the found parameters are. Maybe this will be enough?